# mysqli prepared statments class

Tags: php, class, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am building my first class for mysql statements to make queries easier for myself. Basically we would do.

```
Query::set_config($host,$username,$password);

if( Query::is_database("database_name") ) {
    Query::get_results("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY WHERE `name`=? AND `last`=?",[
        "s"=>"firstname",
        "s"=>"lastname"
    ]);
}
```

My problem is the slight difference between prepared and not, as well as procedural and OO.

Here is the underlying code behind `get_results`

```
/*Load Results from SQL Query*/ 
public static function results($sql,$prepared=null) {
    if($is_configurated) {
        self::connect();
        $rows = array();
        if($prepared === null) {
            $query = mysqli_query(self::$conn,$sql);
            if(!$query) 
                echo mysqli_error(self::$conn);

            while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                $rows[] = $r;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare(self::$conn,$sql);
            /*
                i   corresponding variable has type integer
                d   corresponding variable has type double
                s   corresponding variable has type string
                b   corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
            */
            foreach($prepared as $type=>$param) {
                if(strlen($type) > 1) {
                    self::$errors[]="Only one type is allowed";
                    continue;
                } else {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,$type,$param);
                }
            }

            /*STUCK HERE NOW*/
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                $rows[] = $r;
            }

        }
        self::disconnect();
        return $rows;
    } else return "NO CONFIGURATED CONNECTION";
}
```

I wrote where I am stuck, is this just like a normal `mysqli` `while` where `mysqli_fetch_row` or what. The PHP.net docs aren't very fluid nor right out there. I just need help with doing this and seeing if there are any small flaws in my code. I need to return the rows from the results.

Would this be correct?

```
        /*Load Results from SQL Query*/ 
    public static function results($sql,$prepared=null) {
        if($is_configurated) {
            self::connect();
            $rows = array();
            if($prepared === null) {
                $query = mysqli_query(self::$conn,$sql);
                if(!$query) 
                    echo mysqli_error(self::$conn);

                while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $rows[] = $r;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare(self::$conn,$sql);
                /*
                    i   corresponding variable has type integer
                    d   corresponding variable has type double
                    s   corresponding variable has type string
                    b   corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
                */
                foreach($prepared as $type=>$param) {
                    if(strlen($type) > 1) {
                        self::$errors[]="Only one type is allowed";
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,$type,$param);
                    }
                }

                /*STUCK HERE NOW*/
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $stored = mysqli_store_result($stmt);
                if( count($stored) >= 1) {
                    while ($data = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                        $rows[] = $data;
                    }
                }

            }
            self::disconnect();
            return $rows;
        } else return "NO CONFIGURATED CONNECTION";
    }
```

Comment: `mysqli` does not support named placeholders.

Comment: `?` then right because I know it's either or PDO is named placeholders

Comment: think I have it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use mysqli functions on prepared statements take a look at `mysqli_stmt_get_result` function. However, this function only works with mysqlnd driver.

Comment: @EasyBB I guess it's because you are using `?` in `mysqli` statement without replacing `?` to an actual parameter.

Comment: Yes I figured that I do have to do that. Just want to make sure I'm using prepared so that it's safer.

Comment: @EasyBB Use mysqli_real_escape string for string data and intval for int data when using mysqli and you are safe.

Comment: It's not always fail proof that's why I am writing a prepared statement class

Comment: @EasyBB What do yo mean by fail proof?

Comment: Injection in total. I suck at terminology I really do lol. The purpose of this is to not worry about the back end of this class and write some binded variables to use in the query. It needs some work and I always write my own stuff so I know what's going on behind the scenes